# Rebuilding a tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have a tree in the below form:

```
Node[0]:
       type: "element",
       name: "div",
       data: "",
       attributes:{"class":"wrapper"},
       children: 
                Node[0]:
                        type: "text",
                        name: "",
                        data: "Hello",
                        attributes: {},
                        children: null,
                Node[1]:
                        type: "element",
                        name: "span",
                        data: "",
                        attributes: {"class:leftMenu", "class:Applyshadow"},
                        children: 
                                 Node[0]:
                                        type: "text",
                                        name: "",
                                        data: "World!",
                                        attributes: {},
                                        children: null
Node[1]:
       type: "element",
       name: "div",
       data: "",
       attributes: {"class":"secondDiv", "id":"submit"},
       children: null
```

A node of type "element" can have children and if it does the children are stored as a vector of nodes. I am trying to rebuild the tree with the following class:

```
struct Attribute{
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
};

struct Node{
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
    std::string data;
    std::vector<Attribute> attributes;
    std::vector<Node> children;
 };


class HtmlTree{
    public:
        std::vector<Node> nodes;
        void buildTree(GumboNode*)
}
```

The tree structure comes from gumboNode which is part of gumboParser and in the implementation for the buildTree method I am able to print all the nodes in the tree but stuck on how to store it in the `nodes` vector.

```
Void HtmlTree::buildTree(GumboNode* root){
    print root->type
    vector children = root->children;
    for each child in children:
        if child->type == "element":
            print child->type;
            buildTree(child)
        elif child->type == "text":
            print child->type;
}
```

The above Pseudocode prints the type for all the nodes in the tree..can someone help me out on a way to utilize the same recursive approach to store all the nodes in the vector `nodes`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is it that you have? Where are you going to take the nodes from?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have in mind something like this?

```
void HtmlTree::buildTree(GumboNode *root) {
    nodes = buildTreeImp(root) ;
}

Node HtmlTree::buildTreeImp(GumboNode* root){
    Node result ;
    vector children = root->children;
    for each child in children:
        if child->type == "element": {
            nodes.push_back(buildTree(child))
        elif child->type == "text": {
            Node text_node ;
            text_node.type = child.type ;   
            // set other attributes
            nodes.push_back(text_node) ;
    } 
}
```